# YARN Timeline Service v2 unable to start

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hadoop-yarn, ambari

I have a test HDP cluster setup on AWS for evaluation of a project. The Ambari UI was reporting a number of errors, which when I went through them restarting services as necessary, I encountered trouble with YARN. When starting the Timeline Service Reader V2 for YARN, I get an error

```
2018-08-10 15:51:06,400 INFO  [main] client.RpcRetryingCallerImpl: Call exception, tries=15, retries=15, started=129034 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=Call to HOSTNAME/IPADDRESS:17020 failed on connection exception: org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: HOSTNAME/IPADDRESS:17020, details=row 'prod.timelineservice.entity' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=HOSTNAME,17020,1533827052949, seqNum=-1
```

which eventually results in

```
stderr: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 982, in restart
    self.status(env)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/3.0/services/YARN/package/scripts/timelinereader.py", line 88, in status
    check_process_status(pid_file)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/functions/check_process_status.py", line 43, in check_process_status
    raise ComponentIsNotRunning()
ComponentIsNotRunning

The above exception was the cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/3.0/services/YARN/package/scripts/timelinereader.py", line 108, in <module>
    ApplicationTimelineReader().execute()
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 353, in execute
    method(env)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 993, in restart
    self.start(env, upgrade_type=upgrade_type)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/3.0/services/YARN/package/scripts/timelinereader.py", line 51, in start
    hbase(action='start')
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/3.0/services/YARN/package/scripts/hbase_service.py", line 80, in hbase
    createTables()
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/3.0/services/YARN/package/scripts/hbase_service.py", line 147, in createTables
    logoutput=True)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/base.py", line 166, in __init__
    self.env.run()
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 160, in run
    self.run_action(resource, action)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 124, in run_action
    provider_action()
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/providers/system.py", line 263, in action_run
    returns=self.resource.returns)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 72, in inner
    result = function(command, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 102, in checked_call
    tries=tries, try_sleep=try_sleep, timeout_kill_strategy=timeout_kill_strategy, returns=returns)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 150, in _call_wrapper
    result = _call(command, **kwargs_copy)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 308, in _call
    raise ExecuteTimeoutException(err_msg)
resource_management.core.exceptions.ExecuteTimeoutException: Execution of 'ambari-sudo.sh su yarn-ats -l -s /bin/bash -c 'export  PATH='"'"'/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/lib/ambari-server/*:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/var/lib/ambari-agent'"'"' ; sleep 10;export HBASE_CLASSPATH_PREFIX=/usr/hdp/3.0.0.0-1634/hadoop-yarn/timelineservice/*; /usr/hdp/3.0.0.0-1634/hbase/bin/hbase --config /usr/hdp/3.0.0.0-1634/hadoop/conf/embedded-yarn-ats-hbase org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.timelineservice.storage.TimelineSchemaCreator -Dhbase.client.retries.number=35 -create -s'' was killed due timeout after 300 seconds
```

Which component needs restarting in order to put YARN back in a healthy state and what's the proper way to debug the issue in the future?

Comment: This may be a firewall issue. Turn off the firewall or free the port on which you're trying to run the job. Because the connection refused issue directly point out in that direction only. For more: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/316791/how-to-solve-the-io-netty-channel-abstractchannelannotatedconnectexception-co

Comment: thanks @Abhinav that was originally my thought, but the firewall rules are open between the manager and the agent node. What else might throw a "connection refused" error for that component?

Comment: The other possible reason could be the entry of hosts in your system. If the server couldn't resolve the hostname then also it may send the "connection refused" error.

Comment: @haiqus I am facing the same error. Did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: Anybody able to solve this?

Comment: I’ve encountered a similar issue with an Amazon EMR instance. There, the temp files used by the timeline service filled the drive. Clearing them and restarting fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

If you go into 'background operations' (the gear icon in the Ambari UI), then go to the Timeline Service V2 start link (you may have to click on your machine that is running the Timeline Service first to get there), you should have links in the upper right that say 'copy' and 'open'.  These will hopefully show you error logs in much more detail.

In my case, the Timeline Service V2 couldn't start because there was not enough memory on the system.  It was a small VM cluster just for playing around with only 2GB RAM on each machine.  I found through the more detailed error logs that it was giving an insufficient memory error, so when I upped the VM memory to 4GB, it was able to run.  My best guess is your memory on the main NameNode where your Ambari UI is running isn't enough.  It seems like something around 4GB+ is required, depending on how many services you're running on the main NameNode.